# Two Column Website Resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you create a two column where one of the divs take up the entire screen when rolled over?

Comment: Much more detail required here. What have you tried to make this work yourself?

Comment: Do you have any current mark up with your column layout? You could use javascript or css for the hover depending on your set up / needs / cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really quick example of how this can be done in jquery, if only to give you some direction:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W7jxc/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="col one"></div>
    <div class="col two"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    // Mouse over div
    $(".col").mouseenter(function() {
        // If it's the second div, we want to move it left while making it bigger
        if($(this).hasClass("two")) {
            // we use .stop to stop all current animations
            // Also we add an active class to put it on top
            $(this).stop().addClass("active").animate({"left": "0px", "width": "98%"}, 500);
        }
        // otherwise we dont care, just make it bigger
        else {
             // Also we add an active class to put it on top
            $(this).stop().addClass("active").animate({"width":"98%"}, 500);
        }
    });
    // Mouse off div
    $(".col").mouseleave(function() {
        // If it's the second div, we want to move it back to 45% while making it smaller
        if($(this).hasClass("two")) {
            $(this).stop().animate({"left": "50%", "width":"45%"}, 500).removeClass("active");
        }
        else {
             $(this).stop().animate({"width":"45%"}, 500).removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow this is super helpful! I just wanted to know that I would need to set it up where they are already next to each other right? I just am new to this and really want to figure it out. I appreciate all the help